# Git branch file location

Tags: git, branch

I have almost a hundred branches on my local system, most of them out of date. I want to open the file that contains all the branches so I can easily delete most of them, rather than laboriously removing the branches one by one. Is there a way to do that? A file that we can open to see all the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git you don't have a file containing a list of branches, but a directory containing one file per branch, named exactly after it.

It's `.git/refs/heads`, and for example your master branch consists of the file `.git/refs/heads/master` (no extension) and its content is the commit hash `master` currently points to.

*(note about branches with slashes in the name : they'll be split into the specific directories, i.e. the file for branch `feature/new-homepage` will be in a subdirectory `feature`, and named `new-homepage`)*

---

Also, maybe check [packed refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs). Either to use it on your repo, or to check if anyone has already packed some refs.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to manipulate a repo's internal structure directly, since it could leave the repo in a corrupted state. Using Git's own commands guarantees that everything is kept consistent.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I did not advocate for that. I too think that using git commands to do it is better practice. That's the reason I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each branch in Git is represented by a single text file containing the SHA-1 of the *latest* commit in that branch. Those files are called ["*references*"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).

You can see the paths of the branch *refs* and the respective commit SHA-1 they point to by saying:

```
git show-ref --heads
```

which will return something like:

```
923eccb90415758c74bb3418007bf5691a0d4a1c refs/heads/some-branch
60e2e7f120f5410ec0ba97fa5093bae4dba4ee57 refs/heads/master
```

Now, if you wanted to, you *could* just delete a branch reference by saying:

```
rm .git/refs/heads/some-branch
```

but I wouldn't recommend messing with the repository's internal structure directly; instead, you should use Git's own commands to do that.

For example, say you wanted to delete all the branches that start with the word `feature-`. You could say:

```
git branch --list 'feature-*'
```

to get the list of matching branch names. From there, you could delete those branches by saying:

```
git branch --list 'feature-*' | xargs git branch -D
```

where the [`-D`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--D) option tells Git to delete the branch regardless of whether is has been merged into the current branch or not.